# Definition of an ideal in a L-language

Tags: logic, model-theory

> Let $\mathcal{L}_\text{ring}=\{0,1,+, \cdot, I\}$ where $0,1$ are constants, $+, \cdot$ are binary function symbols and $I$ is an unary relation symbol.
>
> Give $\mathcal{L}$-formulas which express that the subset defined by $I$ is:
>
> a) an ideal
>
> b) a prime ideal
>
> c) a maximal ideal

I would write down the following for a):
$$I(0) \wedge \forall x \forall y(I(x) \wedge I(y) \rightarrow I(x+y)) \wedge \forall x \forall y(I(y) \rightarrow I(x\cdot y)\wedge I(y\cdot x))$$
Would this be right?

b) Can I just write?
$$\forall x\forall y I(x\cdot y) \rightarrow I(x)\vee I(y)$$

c) The assistant-professor wrote:
$$\forall x[\neg I(x) \rightarrow \forall y\exists i\exists u (y=i+(u\cdot x) \wedge I(i))]$$
Could someone explain this further, I don't really follow...

Comment: As a small note, "an" rather than "a" should be used in front of "$L$-language". "$L$-formula", or any other expression starting with an $L$ that is pronounced as "ell".

Answer (score 1):

Your answer for (a) is fine. Your answer for (b) is almost right: you also need to specify that the ideal isn’t the whole ring, so you want

$$\forall x\,\forall y\big(I(x\cdot y)\to I(x)\lor I(y)\big)\land \exists x\big(\neg I(x)\big)\;.$$

Now let’s take a look at (c); the question is why

$$\forall x\Big(\neg I(x)\to\forall y\,\exists i\,\exists u\big(y=i+(u\cdot x)\land I(i)\big)\Big)\tag{1}$$

expresses the fact that the subset defined by $I$ is a maximal ideal.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$and let $I$ be an ideal in $R$. Suppose that $I$ is maximal. Then by definition if $J$ is an ideal of $R$ such that $I\subseteq J\subseteq R$, then either $J=I$ or $J=R$. Suppose that $x\in R\setminus I$. Then $I+Rx$ is an ideal of $R$, and $I\subseteq I+Rx$, since $0\in Rx$. But $$x=0+1\cdot x\in I+Rx$$ as well, so $I+Rx\ne I$, and therefore $I+Rx=R$. Thus, for each $x\in R\setminus I$ there are an $i\in I$ and a $u\in R$ such that $x=i+(u\cdot x)$. Thus, $(1)$ must hold if the set defined by $I$ is to be a maximal ideal.

If $(1)$ does hold, it’s not hard to check that the set defined by $I$ is either a maximal ideal or all of the ring. Call that set $I$ and the ring $R$; $(1)$ says that $I+Rx=R$ for all $x\in R\setminus I$. If $I$ is not maximal, let $J$ be an ideal such that $I\subsetneqq J\subsetneqq R$, and let $x\in J\setminus I$. Then $I+Rx\subseteq J$, so $I+Rx\ne R$. The only problem is that $(1)$ doesn’t exclude the possibility that $I=R$, so we need to replace it with

$$\forall x\Big(\neg I(x)\to\forall y\,\exists i\,\exists u\big(y=i+(u\cdot x)\land I(i)\big)\Big)\land\exists x\big(\neg I(x)\big)\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

(a) Looks right to me. The solution to (c) looks like you're supposed to be considering *commutative* rings, in which case you'd only need one of $I(x\cdot y)$ and $I(y\cdot x)$.

(b) Looks right too, assuming you already know $I$ is an ideal -- except that the whole ring does not usually count as a prime ideal. So you should add as an additional condition that $\neg I(1)$.

(c) What we really want to do is to claim "there is no ideal that is a proper superset of $I$ but is not the entire ring". But we cannot do that directly here, because the language doesn't allow us to quantify over ideals. Instead the solution uses the *trick* of considering the smallest ideal that contains both $I$ and some element $x\notin I$. This ideal is
$$ I+\langle x\rangle  = \{ i + ux \mid i\in I, u\in R \} $$
and the formula claim that if $x$ is not in $I$ this is the entire ring. It should be clear that this is true if $I$ is actually maximal (just show that the above set is always an ideal). On the other hand, if $I$ were *not* maximal, then there would be an ideal $J$ with $I\subsetneq J\subsetneq R$. In that case we can choose $x\in J\setminus I$, and then it we can see that $i+ux$ must be in $J$ for every $i\in I, u\in R$. Thus, $I+\langle x\rangle$ is *not* all of $R$.

Instead of quantifying over all $y$ it would be sufficient to test for $1$ being in $I+\langle x\rangle$, that is
$$ \forall x[\neg I(x)\to \exists i\exists u(1=i+ux \land I(i))] $$